# Is what I pass to resolve or reject gets assigned to a variable or error object?

Tags: javascript

I have this simple example:

```
function getUsers() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        "use strict";
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (Math.random() * 5 > 2) {
                resolve(usersPassed);
            } else {
                reject(errorPassed);
            }
        }, 2000);
    });
}

async function getFirstUserAwait() {
    try {
        const usersObtained = await getUsers();
        return usersObtained[0];
    } catch (errorObtained) {
        console.log(errorObtained);
    }
}
```

My question is whether what I pass to resolve here, `users` object:

```
resolve(usersPassed);
```

gets assigned to a variable

```
const usersObtained = await getUsers();
```

...

```
usersPassed === usersObtained; // true
```

?

And the same holds for `reject`?

```
reject(errorPassed);
```

...

```
} catch (errorReceived) {

errorPassed === errorReceived // true
```

I've done tests and it seems to be so, just wanted to make sure there is nothing  more to this, just a syntactic sugar.

Comment: Should be the case, from my understanding of `async`/`await`.

Comment: @mc10, got it, thanks